# iOS 8/9 - Custom Styling(Bold) of UIAlertController action buttons

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9, uialertcontroller

I have an UIAlertController with a 'Cancel' and 'Ok' option and 'Cancel' is in bold by default. Is there a way to remove the bold from 'Cancel' and instead bold the 'Ok' title in that option?

EDIT:

it seems that whenever you use: UIAlertActionStyleCancel its style is set to Bold but wanted to set another option to Bold without giving it the UIAlertActionStyleCancel style. (doesnt seem like this is possible without a bunch of workarounds)

Answer (score 0):

Just set your OK button to style Cancel, its a silly way of doing it but it works. Your other option is finding a 3rd party tool and packaging it into your app.

Comment: If i set it to style cancel then by default it gets put in the first option instead of the second option. I want to keep Cancel as the first option and "OK" as the second option but not bold cancel.

Comment: How bout having them both as default or OK style? But then neither will be  bolded, but it will be in the right order.

Comment: no i wanted one of them bolded but not the cancel - that was my problem to begin with. There should(i mean apple should provide a way) to be a way to do this